# Python no longer found after deactivating conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, git-bash

[image]

I'm working with git-bash on win10, trying to set up a conda environment. I notice the following behaviour:

```
/c/r2/tutorial (master)
$ which python
/c/Miniconda3/python

/c/r2/tutorial (master)
$ source activate /c/Miniconda3/envs/morepath/
(/c/Miniconda3/envs/morepath/)
/c/r2/tutorial (master)
$ which python
/c/Miniconda3/envs/morepath/python
(/c/Miniconda3/envs/morepath/)
/c/r2/tutorial (master)
$ source deactivate /c/Miniconda3/envs/morepath/

/c/r2/tutorial
$ which python
/c/r2/tutorial
$
```

My environmental variables are in the screenshot. What is this occuring? How can I fix it?

Comment: I resolved a similar situation, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/46277649/6107564, wish this would help.