# Conda activate/deactivate environment breaking PATH

Tags: python, bash, path, anaconda, conda

I am finding that when I create a Conda environment `source activate environment` and then deactivate that environment `source deactivate environment`, my native bash commands no longer work.

I've attached an image of ls working before enabling an environment and then not afterwards. I assume that this is something because of my PATH - but I am a novice and am not sure specifically what to fix. I am doing this in Git Bash on Windows. Anaconda 3 and Python 3.5.

[Please work ls, come on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUKQ2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your conda environment is replacing the parameters and environment variables defined in your local bash profile. I am sure if you open a new environment(bash session), you will find everything is working fine.

I would suggest you add a command to reload bash profile after deactivating the environment, so that the profile variable values will again be applied. It should solve the problem.

Comment: Got it - just marked as answered. I didn't realize I could add that line to my profile. Would it be possible to add a small line/script if folks come back to this page in the future? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few bugs in the activate/deactivate scripts, which I've fixed in versions I call activate.cygwin and deactivate.cygwin.

- activate.cygwin: fixes 2 places where the conda command returns a string with a return "\r" at the end that confounds processing.
- deactivate.cygwin: fixes conversion of /cygdrive/... to avoid error
  CondaValueError: Could not find environment: /cygdrivec:\Users\rjp\Anaconda2\envs...

I've posted the modified scripts to https://bitbucket.org/snippets/plevin/. See instructions at the top of activate.cygwin.

Comment: Oh, this seems very relevant to my problem. I'm getting stray "\r"s crashing the deactivate script. But I have the recent-version conda that seems to delegate everything to conda.exe, so I'm not sure where I could apply this patch...

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to deactivate a conda environment is to run `conda deactivate`, rather than `source deactivate environment`

Source: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html?highlight=activate#deactivating-an-environment

Comment: yeah.. we just need to run conda deactivate

Comment: For now in 2023, we have to initialize the conda once this installation step is done, to do that run the following two commands
`~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash
~/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh
`

Answer (score 0):

I use Git Bash in Windows 10 and encountered the same problem too. The previous answer does not work for me, probably because I don't have any path set in ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc.

I checked my path variable in a fresh git bash, it looks like:

> /c/Users/chen_x/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/chen_x/bin....(more)

After `. C:/Users/chen_x/Miniconda3/Scripts/activate C:/Users/chen_x/Miniconda3` and `. activate snowflakes`, the path becomes:

> /C/Users/chen_x/Miniconda3/envs/snowflakes:(blalbla..):C:\Users\chen_x\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\chen_x\Miniconda3;....(more)

I assume that git bash does not recognize pathes like `C:\program files...`, then added the following line to `C:/Users/chen_x/Miniconda3/Scripts/activate` right after the last `EXPORT PATH=` command (about line 78):

```
export PATH="$($_CONDA_PYTHON -c "import re; p=re.sub(r'\\\', r'/', r'$PATH'); p=re.sub('(;|:)([A-Z]):', lambda m: ':/'+m.group(2).lower(), p); print(p)")"
```

It works.

By the way, I create a ~/condaenv script to start conda environment:

```
#!/bin/bash
. C:/Users/chen_x/Miniconda3/Scripts/activate C:/Users/chen_x/Miniconda3
```

It would be convinent to :

```
. ~/condaenv
. activate snowflakes
```